# How to track firebase analytics screen time of android fragment?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, tracking, screen-time

Screen time is automatically tracked for Android `Activity`. But `Fragment` doesn't seem to track automatically.

I added the following code to `BaseFragment`, from which all my Fragments inherit.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    val firebaseAnalytics = Analytics.getInstance(requireContext())
    val bundle = Bundle().apply {
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, this::class.java.simpleName.toString())
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, this::class.java.simpleName.toString())
    }
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle)
}
```

There are too many Fragments I am using, so I thought I could create a `BaseFragment` to track the screen time.

But the problem is not being tracked. Why is this?